# Chrome Browser Uncaught TypeError in Handlebars Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

Hi I am using following code to display durations with handlebars template. But Chrome browser says error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Please assist me what I am doing wrong.

JSON:

```
duration : ["monthly", "yearly"]
```

Template:

```
{{#each duration}}
    <input type="radio" name="duration" id="{{.}}" class="mLZero {{#ifCond . 'monthly'}}ns-month {{else}}ns-year {{/ifCond}}" />
    <label type="radio" name="duration" for="{{.}}"  class="fCaps mR10 {{#ifCond . 'monthly'}}ns-month {{else}}ns-year {{/ifCond}}">{{.}}</label>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might be experiencing the issue documented here: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/830 that is particular to Google Chrome 36.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already noticed the link, they told issue will be fixed in Google Chrome 38.